# How to delay a method until another is finished first , javascript?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I'm currently working on a project for school using a pokemon api that will display the information needed to evolve the pokemon (please note that I'm completely new to javascript and HTML).
Link :http://pokeapi.co/docsv2/
The website will ask the user for a name and that name will be used to get a url for the main information that I'm looking for.
For example : if someone enters in pikachu, the program will request the object for pikachu which contains the url for pikachu's evolution chain and that url is the one that will provide the main information for the website.
Currently the code looks like this:

```
var pokemon = new XMLHttpRequest();
var name = prompt("Whats the name of the pokemon you have?").toLowerCase();
var url = "http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon-species/" + name;
var url2;


pokemon.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(pokemon.readyState == 4 && pokemon.status == 200){
        var myArr = JSON.parse(pokemon.responseText);
        var url2 = myArr.evolution_chain; 

    }
}
pokemon2.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (pokemon2.readyState == 4 && pokemon2.status == 200) {
        var myArr2 = JSON.parse(pokemon2.responseText);
        console.log(myArr2.chain.species.name);
    }
}
var pokemon2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
pokemon2.open("GET", url2, true).done(onreadystatechange);
pokemon2.send();

pokemon.open("GET", url, true);
pokemon.send();
```

However the program doesn't work due to the fact that the getting is occurring at the same time and pokemon2 should only be called after pokemon is finished because it's getting the actual url for pokemon2.
Does anyone know how to be able to accomplish this?
Many thanks! :).

Comment: Use JS callback? Or JS promise?

Answer (score 1):

You can call `pokemon2` once `pokemon` finishes:

```
pokemon.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(pokemon.readyState == 4 && pokemon.status == 200){
        var myArr = JSON.parse(pokemon.responseText);
        var url2 = myArr.evolution_chain; 

        // Call pokemon2 here
        var pokemon2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
        pokemon2.open("GET", url2, true);
        pokemon2.send();

    }
}
```